# Mount but exclude one subfolder?

Tags: mount, symlink, nas, unmounting, synology

I have a Synology NAS in which I use the following command at NAS startup to create a symlink, which works fine:

`mount --bind "/volume1/SourceFolder" "/volume1/SymlinkFolder"`

Now I have a new requirement, which is that inside `SourceFolder`, there's a folder several levels down called `FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink` which needs to be excluded from the symlink folder. In order to do this, I thought the `--make-unbindable` option might work, which might prevent this folder showing up in `SymlinkFolder` when the above command is run, but it doesn't work. If I execute this:

`mount --make-unbindable "/volume1/SourceFolder/blah/blah/blah/FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink"`

I get this error:

`mount: /volume1/SourceFolder/blah/blah/blah/FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink: not mount point or bad option.`

Anyone know what's wrong ?

Is there any other way of excluding a subfolder when creating a symlink using `mount` command ?

Comment: Are these `mount` commands run on the NAS - or on a client?

Comment: @Seamus Running on the NAS via SSH

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you contact Synology tech support. Their platform is actually far removed from a normal Linux setup.